# How to solve backslash issue in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I write WordPress theme options text editor **Guard's Room**  text and frontend show/print it **Guard\'s Room** But I need **Guard's Room**

So how can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Where ever you `echo` your data please use [stripslashes()](http://curtismchale.ca/2010/12/09/using-stripslashes-with-theme-options/) before `echo`. See below example.

```
echo stripslashes( get_option( 'THEME_OPTION_NAME' ) );
```